# How to SUM and GroupBy on Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So, i want to group by the `api` and sum the values from `visit`, this is the query:

```
SELECT api, tanggal, SUM(visit) as visit FROM `counters` GROUP BY api
```

I try to run the query from phpmyadmin, but when i implement it using Eloquent ORM on Laravel like this:

```
$statistic = Counter::selectRaw('api, tanggal, SUM(visit) as visit')
            ->groupBy('api')
            ->get();

dd($statistic);
```

It gets an error message that says
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'web_opd.counters.tanggal' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select api, tanggal, SUM(visit) as visit from` counters`group by`api`)`

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

All the columns which appear in the select clause generally have to also appear in group by.  Here are two valid versions of your query:

```sql
SELECT api, tanggal, SUM(visit) AS visit
FROM counters
GROUP BY api, tanggal;

SELECT api, SUM(visit) AS visit
FROM counters
GROUP BY api;
```

Assuming the latter is what you really want, your PHP code becomes:

```php
$statistic = Counter::selectRaw('api, SUM(visit) AS visit')
    ->groupBy('api')
    ->get();
```